# OpenID persona image

Tags: feature-request, support, openid, images

How can I get SO to take the picture from my openid persona as my SO profile picture?

Update:
And if I can't, can this be added as a feature?

Answer (score 3):

Pictures are used from [**Gravatar**](http://www.gravatar.com).  Sign up there and set things up.  It matches images from Gravatar based on email address.

Comment: I thought the whole idea of openID is to have ONE identity that you can use everywhere. I'll probably be without a profile image then since gravatar does not support openID. What a load of bollocks.

Comment: @mattilyra: I thought openID was just for authentication. A profile and specifically a picture is a whole other business, no?

Comment: If gravatar supported OpenID as well, you could have just one identity.

Comment: Yes exactly. Didn't Facebook become an openID provider some time ago as well.

Comment: Gravatar sucks for people (like me) who use plus addressing - eg. myname+yoursitename@mydomain.com. I really hope Stack Overflow changes this to allow another way to add profile images in the future :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an account with [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com) (use the same picture as the one from your OpenID persona)
2. Use your Gravatar email address as the email address in your SO profile
3. ???
4. Profit!

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  SO does not use the OpenID profile image, only Gravatar.  This choice was made early on due to the limited support most openid providers had for the profile image.

I don't know if the situation is any better now than it was 18 months ago, but consider asking for this as a feature request.